# Make Pycharm treat single and double quotes the same in searches

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on some code which is partly my own and partly copied from a colleague's program. When accessing dictionaries I usually use `example["key"]` whereas he usually uses `example['key']`, I'm refactoring some code and while pycharm has an excellent search and replace function it treats single and double quotes separately which is A) inconvenient and B) means there is a good chance of me missing some code.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get Pycharm to treat single and double quotes the same for the purposes of find and/or search and replace i.e. so a search for `dictionary['hello_world']` would find both `dictionary['hello_world']` and `dictionary["hello_world"]`.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a linter? Python black is a very common one https://pypi.org/project/black/

Comment: I don't know a way where PyCharm will treat " and ' the same. I would suggest to search for " and replace all by ' (or other way round) because it doesn't matter in the code.

Comment: @QuagTeX I wanted to suggest the same, but I have to add that it might be the case that the op has single and double quotes inside strings, so a blind search-and-replace might break a few things.

Comment: @Sasszem good point. I haven't considered that you can use single and double quotes inside strings aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex in search box ".*" and operator OR with symbol "|":

[image]

Thank you